# Hosting a React App from Google Cloud Storage 404 status code

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am hosting a React App from Google Cloud Storage and I have setup the bucket to use index.html as the main and error page so I can always load up the index.html page but I get a 404 when accessing the page. I don't know if this is the best way to handle this. I guess the problem is that I need React to use url rewriting and always load up the html and since the bucket can't really redirect the way I need it to this is happening.

Are there alternatives such as serving at least the index page from an actual server and load balancer?

Comment: Have you investigated [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)?

Comment: Or as an alternative [this](https://github.com/ncruces/appengine-hosting) GitHub project?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that Github App Engine Go App and it worked perfectly

Comment: Glad it helped.